# Cannot run pyflink official table tutorial example on macos

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I copied the complete example from [table_api_tutorial](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/python/table_api_tutorial/), I can run the example on centos, and My java colleague can run the example on his macbook.

env:

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)
macos big sur 11.4

$ jenv version
oracle64-1.8.0.181

python3.7.12 or python3.8.12

$ pip list|grep flink
apache-flink                      1.14.0
apache-flink-libraries            1.14.0
```

error:

```
~/workspace/learns/flink_learn/aflink$ python table.py
Executing word_count example with default input data set.
Use --input to specify file input.
Printing result to stdout. Use --output to specify output path.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "table.py", line 132, in <module>
    word_count(known_args.input, known_args.output)
  File "table.py", line 107, in word_count
    .execute_insert('sink') \
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyflink/table/table_result.py", line 76, in wait
    get_method(self._j_table_result, "await")()
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1286, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o164.await.
: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to wait job finish
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.awaitInternal(TableResultImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.await(TableResultImpl.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to wait job finish
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.InsertResultIterator.hasNext(InsertResultIterator.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.hasNext(TableResultImpl.java:370)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.isFirstRowReady(TableResultImpl.java:383)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.lambda$awaitInternal$1(TableResultImpl.java:116)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1626)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.InsertResultIterator.hasNext(InsertResultIterator.java:54)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.doForward(FutureUtils.java:1389)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$null$1(ClassLoadingUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$guardCompletionWithContextClassLoader$2(ClassLoadingUtils.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$1.onComplete(AkkaFutureUtils.java:47)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:300)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:297)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:221)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$DirectExecutionContext.execute(AkkaFutureUtils.java:65)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:284)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:284)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:284)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:621)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:24)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:23)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:532)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:138)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:228)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:218)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:209)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:679)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:444)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:314)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:217)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create stage bundle factory! Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyflink/fn_execution/beam/beam_boot.py", line 38, in <module>
    from apache_beam.portability.api.beam_fn_api_pb2_grpc import BeamFnExternalWorkerPoolStub
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from apache_beam import coders
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from apache_beam.coders.coders import *
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 43, in <module>
    from future.moves import pickle
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/future/moves/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import_top_level_modules()
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/future/standard_library/__init__.py", line 810, in import_top_level_modules
    with exclude_local_folder_imports(*TOP_LEVEL_MODULES):
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/future/standard_library/__init__.py", line 781, in __enter__
    module = __import__(m, level=0)
  File "/Users/ken/workspace/learns/flink_learn/aflink/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode()
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyflink/table/environment_settings.py", line 267, in in_streaming_mode
    get_gateway().jvm.EnvironmentSettings.inStreamingMode())
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyflink/java_gateway.py", line 62, in get_gateway
    _gateway = launch_gateway()
  File "/Users/ken/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyflink/java_gateway.py", line 86, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("It's launching the PythonGatewayServer during Python UDF execution "
Exception: It's launching the PythonGatewayServer during Python UDF execution which is unexpected. It usually happens when the job codes are in the top level of the Python script file and are not enclosed in a `if name == 'main'` statement.

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.open(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:255)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:131)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.python.AbstractStatelessFunctionOperator.open(AbstractStatelessFunctionOperator.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.python.table.PythonTableFunctionOperator.open(PythonTableFunctionOperator.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:711)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:687)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:654)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:958)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:927)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:766)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:575)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 0
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:451)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:303)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:564)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process died with exit code 0
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager$RunningProcess.isAliveOrThrow(ProcessManager.java:75)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:112)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:252)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:231)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, I find a similar question [about apache_beam.coders.coders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56224534/how-to-fix-attributeerror-module-apache-beam-coders-coders-has-no-attribute). So just rename `test.py` to another name.